# google maps event listener only running once

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am opening a modal on click to show a google map.  As the site is responsive I added an event listener to make sure the map is centered on window resize.  All of this works, but the event listener only runs on the initial modal open.  If I close the modal and open it up again the listener no longer works/runs and there is no centering on map resizing.

Ideas?

```
// show google map
$('#datatable').on('click', '.dtMap', function () {

    var data = {'activity_id': $(this).parents('tr').attr('id')};

    // equals 40.0989, -83.1615, but need to make into two variables or in this case an array
    var latlong = $(this).closest('tr').find('.latlong').text();
    var coordinates = latlong.split(', ');

    $('#modal-ajax')
    //this event fires when the modal has finished the animation
    //the size of #map_canvas is available now
    //create the map when this event fires
    .one('shown.bs.modal', function(){

        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coordinates[0]), parseFloat(coordinates[1]));

        var mapOptions = {
             zoom: 12,
             center: latLng,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },

            map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], mapOptions),

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'test'
            });

        // make sure the map and marker stays centered on resizing
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center); 
        });

    })

    .load('/modals/m_view_map.php', data, function() {
        google.load('maps', '3',
            {other_params:'sensor=false', 
                callback: function(){
                    //show the modal
                    $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');
                }
            }
        );

    });

});
```

**SOLUTION:**

Why I never thought of this before... this properly centers the map/marker on resizing at all times...

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(latLng); 
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#modal-ajax')
    //this event fires when the modal has finished the animation
    //the size of #map_canvas is available now
    //create the map when this event fires
    .one('shown.bs.modal', function(){
```

Yes it will work once, because you are using [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method of jQuery and along with all the map event variable are scoped locally within the method itself.  Therefore it is not working.

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element per event type.

Comment: I see what your saying, but can't seem to get that... I would think the best even would be on map open, but there is no event for that.